# SDL2 - Keyboard events for character movement have unexpected behavior

Tags: c++, sdl-2, keyboard-events

I'm currently working on a small game and recently tried to introduce smoother movements for the player using velocity variables: when a key is pressed, the velocity is increased in the appropriate direction; and, when the same key is released, the velocity goes back to 0. However, when moving on the y axis, the character won't stop moving as it should when the key is released, which is weird considering everything works as intended when moving on the x axis.

Here's the function responsible for keyboard events:

```cpp
void Game::processEvent(){                                                 
       switch(Engine::Instance().event.type){                                                                                               
         case SDL_KEYDOWN:                                                      
           switch(Engine::Instance().event.key.keysym.sym){                     
             case SDLK_LEFT: Entities[0]->vx=-0.0001f; break;  //Entities is a vector filled with pointers to objects like enemies, the player etc..               
             case SDLK_RIGHT: Entities[0]->vx=0.0001f; break;  //This is how velocity is set               
             case SDLK_UP: Entities[0]->vy=-0.0001f; break;                     
             case SDLK_DOWN: Entities[0]->vy=0.0001f; break;                    
           }                                                                    
           break;                                                               
         case SDL_KEYUP:                                                        
             switch(Engine::Instance().event.key.keysym.sym){ //Reset velocity in a direction only if the player was previously moving in that direction                  
               case SDLK_LEFT: if(Entities[0]->vx>0) Entities[0]->vx=0.0f; break; 
               case SDLK_RIGHT: if(Entities[0]->vx<0) Entities[0]->vx=0.0f; break;
               case SDLK_UP: if(Entities[0]->vy<0) Entities[0]->vy=0.0f; break; 
               case SDLK_DOWN: if (Entities[0]->vy>0) Entities[0]->vy=0.0f; break;
             }                                                                  
             break;                                                                                                                         
         default:                                                               
             break;                                                               
      } 
    }
```

And the function used to update objects' position:

```cpp
    void Entity::updatePos(){                           
    x += vx;    //Velocity is added to the sprite's coords                                      
    y += vy;                                          
    dstrect = {static_cast<int>(x*800), static_cast<int>(y*800), static_cast<int>(w*800), static_    cast<int>(h*800)}; //Workaround to make sprites' coords and dimensions always relative to the screen, not great I know XD that's why x and y are floats between 0 and 1.
    }
```

I've been scratching my head for a while as to why `vy` isn't reset properly when `vx` is. Any idea?

Comment: Have you tried stepping through your code with a debugger and look at what the variables are doing? Are you sure the KeyUp-Event gets fired? And with this kind of code, it's VERY easy to mix up variable names. Quite possibly it's just a copy&paste error.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your help! You're probably right, typos in variables' name are my personal hell XD The KeyUp event does get fired tho, well at least for the up and down key...I'll look more into it

Answer (score 1):

EDIT: Removing the 'if' statements before setting the velocity to 0 solved the problem, guess it was unnecessary in the first place.

Which give us instead:

```
case SDL_KEYUP:                   
switch(Engine::Instance().event.key.keysym.sym){
case SDLK_LEFT: Entities[0]->vx=0; break;
case SDLK_RIGHT: Entities[0]->vx=0; break;
case SDLK_UP: Entities[0]->vy=0; break;
case SDLK_DOWN: Entities[0]->vy=0; break;
default: break;
```

(I can't flag this as the answer yet, sorry 'bout that)